# Is it poor form to make serial revisions to your own questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users, editing-help

A habit I've developed over years of editing fora and articles online is, having made a post or created a document, I'll review it and immediately notice at least two or three minor corrections I could make. My usual response has simply been to make the corrections since altering your own posts is not generally subject to review. In this way, some of my posts, both on Stack Exchange and elsewhere, may receive ten or twelve edits, by me, in their first day, depending on how nit-picky I'm feeling or how terrible a job I've done to begin with.

Most of the edits create some improvement in the readability or clarity of the post, without changing the core point or revising it in a way that meaningfully alters its purpose; sometimes I might think of a better word, or correct some piece of punctuation, or realize that my little jokes aren't funny and ought better to cut them out. The edits are seldom profound, though they do improve the quality of the piece at least somewhat-- sometimes significantly when taken together.

So my question is this: Should I bother, and does it create problems? I know that other people may end up losing *their* edits-in-progress if some minor edit I make jumps past them while they're working, but I also realize the likelihood of this is rather remote. On the one hand, our posts are our own to curate and maintain, and it's not as if these edits create some mountain of unseen spam notifications for someone somewhere[, right??]. But there are also guidelines for making edits to *other peoples'* posts, and there is probably an argument to be made for observing those guidelines on our own.

I usually do my best to roll as many edits into a single update as I can, but that doesn't mean I succeed. Because there is no mechanism limiting it (currently), I imagine that it's not really a problem and that individual users' discretion is usually good enough, but it couldn't hurt to hear more about it.

Is there some protocol regarding the frequency of revising our own posts?

Comment: I, personally, am annoyed when I'm reading, answering or editing a question only to notice that it gets edited while I'm doing so. I use the inline refresh option so if you bother me with another edit while I am performing my task, there's a fat chance I'll just ignore your question altogether. If you know you need multiple edits after posing a question then that means it requires more attention before posting.

Comment: I feel like I've considerably underestimated the number of users who post crappy, poorly-thought-out questions but hang around for ages trying to fix them...

Comment: I was disappointed to not see at least 1 edit on this post by you :(

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That's why I try not to jump into editing in first seconds of question's lifetime.

Comment: @Jeroen It is more a personal style of writing.  Some are happy to dump out comprehensible-enough words into the box and click Save.  Some are paying more attention to style and content and may spend some time making sure the question looks and feels just right. Certain details often make themselves known only after you feel you have "finished editing".

Comment: It is better to correct a mistake when found.  Presumably waiting a certain period would be good, but it's hard to know what threshold to use here.

Comment: I sometimes tried to use this technique deliberately, as every edit brings my question back onto the main page :-)

Comment: [This image](http://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/9d/03/71/9d0371f03d79c752ac330a13e505d8d9.jpg) & several others with same quote...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

My rule of thumb is, edit as much as you want, but try not to create too many revisions, and try not to confuse people by adding loads of new information or changing the *basic meaning* of your post.

Rewording and correcting your work to make it clearer and more concise I find totally acceptable, though, at any time and as often as one wants.

Note that not *every* change you make is logged separately:

- Any changes you make within the first five minutes after creating a post do not create a new revision.
- Each new revision you create *also* has a five-minute window. Changes during that time count towards one and the same revision.

Comment: I have added a fair amount of new information (often, but not always, in the form of an additional code block), but when I do that I *always* add it to the end after a header marking it as an addition that has been added after the fact.  Never been complained at, so that seems to work for people.  Otherwise, if I feel there's something significant to add from comments I may do the same or I may work it into the original text, after acknowledging in the comments that I'm going to do so.  The primary barometer is not how much is being added, but communicating that you're doing so.

Answer (score 29):

Here's how I see it. Note here that while I'm sensitive to the desire to gain rep, my goal is **not** to *maximize anybody's rep* but to *minimize the annoyance of seeing a post being edited constantly*. "Oh, a new question. Hm... no, that's Bob who edited his question **again**. %$^#$!"

#### For Questions

You have all the time in the world to polish your question. So take your time. Write it in an editor of your choice (I use Emacs), put it aside for an hour (specific time to be refined with experience), do other stuff, come back to it. Chances are that you are going to see things to fix that you **can** fix before posting.

I've often taken a whole week to write a question (not full time, of course). I've never been scooped.

#### For Answers

If the Fastest Gun in the West problem is not a factor (e.g. you are answering an old question that is probably not very visible), then do the same thing as for questions above.

If the Fastest Gun in the West is a factor then I realize you want to post as fast as possible but:

- Your first edition should answer the question. No "I'm writing an answer now" nonsense. No answer missing substantial information.
- Once your first edition is out, you've staked your claim. If you see a major mistake (e.g. the code won't run) by all means edit it right away but please edit typos in one shot rather than in a dozen edits.

Comment: Worth knowing, but the context of the question was more to do with revisions that create *minor* improvements, rather than finalizing a partial or hurried post. I have no fear of being scooped, rest assured; if I can find a question that hasn't been asked and answered in the several years of this site's history, I doubt it'll happen in the little while it takes me to compose my own properly. XD

Answer (score 1):

I'd mention that editing a question to provide code (or more code) or to offer what was attempted and how that is different from the expected result is not a problem.

It's when the question *changes* from the original question that it's best asked in another question.